# Custom property name binding for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: asp.net-web-api

For `application/json` or `application/xml` I can use `DataContract` for a custom property name binding:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Method([FromBody]Model request)
{
}

[DataContract]
public class Model
{
    [DataMember(Name="custom_name")]
    public string CustomName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use `DataContract` or something else for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API form-urlencoded binding to different property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997913/web-api-form-urlencoded-binding-to-different-property-names)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter implementation for form-urlencoded that you can use. It should work against any POCO class (Your data contract should work as well but it would ignore the DataContract attributes),

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formurlencodedmediatypeformatter(v=vs.108).aspx

Make sure you have that media type formatter configured in your web api.

Comment: FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter and JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter not work with DataContract

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MSDN post on setting the DataContractFormat: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/05/15/using-datacontracts-with-wcf-web-api.aspx

The [MediaTypeFormatterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformattercollection%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class contains [FormUrlEncodedFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformattercollection.formurlencodedformatter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). You could try the above post to set your DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but maybe this could helps other people. Here is a solution with [ModelBinder and AliasAttribute](https://gist.github.com/ToineSeiter/5e124769b09ab425952526958f9caa06)  to do this kind of code :

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(AliasBinder))]
public class MyModel
{
    [Alias("state")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42203608/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)