# Web API Form - Url Encoded Complex Parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Deserializing a complex type in WebAPI is giving me serious grief.
The data contains keys that are syntactically invalid in c# as property names.
How can I translate the key names?

Relevant: [Web API form-urlencoded binding to different property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997913/web-api-form-urlencoded-binding-to-different-property-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own [url encoded object deserializer](https://github.com/mnelsonwhite/URLEncodedDeserializeWebAPI/blob/master/FormUrlEncode.cs) that made use of the `JsonProperty` attribute. Then I used it with a custom `modelbinder`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)'s `JsonProperty` to do the trick:

```
public class SomeModel {
    [JsonProperty("YourCustomName")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter will recognize that attribute?

Comment: Looks like for the purposes of JSON deserialization and serialization it works but not for form urlencoded data.