# DataMember Name not respected when using WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following class that I use in my WebApi2 service.

```
[DataContract()]
public class TokenRequest
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "badge_number")]
    public String BadgeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the class's properties are aliased with `[DataMember(Name = "...")]`

Using the following controller

```
[Route("Service/GetToken")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetToken(TokenRequest request) { ... }
```

I had hoped to get a TokenRequest object with the following POST body

```
last_name=Stillwell&badge_number=0000
```

However, both `request.LastName` and `request.BadgeNumber` are null.

Now, if I make the request like so:

```
LastName=Stillwell&BadgeNumber=0000
```

`request.LastName` and `request.BadgeNumber` will have the correct values. Why isn't `[DataMember(Name = "...")]` pulling in my values when I use `last_name` or `badge_number`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API form-urlencoded binding to different property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997913/web-api-form-urlencoded-binding-to-different-property-names)

Comment: @Dayan, I am. Hence the `[HttpPost]` attribute on the controller.

Comment: Without seeing more it is hard to tell, but my guess is that the application is using the Newtonsoft library to handle it's de/serialization of the JSON objects in which case you would want to use the JsonProperty attribute, for instance `[JsonProperty("last_name")]` on the LastName property of the TokenRequest class;

Comment: @peinearydevelopment a previous (now deleted) answer suggested that. However, the result was the same. I received null values from the request.

Comment: did you try making it with the POST body like this: `{"last_name":"Stillwell","badge_number"="000"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by returning `TokenRequest` in the Controller.

```
[Route("Service/GetToken")]
[HttpPost]
public TokenRequest GetToken(TokenRequest request) { ... }
```

Then, in my WebApiConfig.cs file I added the following

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

This returns JSON instead of XML. See: [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)